# Dot product of one row against all rows in a many-column mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

### Background:

I have a ~400,000 row table which looks like the following:

```
+---------+--------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+
|   ID    |  WORD  | COL0 | COL1  | COL2 | ... | COL500 |
+---------|--------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+
|    0    | DOG    | -0.73| 0.77  | 0.15 |     | -0.55  |
|    1    | CAT    | 0.41 | -0.57 | 0.61 |     | 0.00   |
|    2    | HOUSE  | 0.40 | 0.32  | -0.23|     | 0.52   |
|   ...   |        |      |       |      |     |        | 
| 400000  | LOVE   | 0.51 | 0.59  | 0.01 |     | -0.10  |
+---------+--------+------+-------+------+-----+--------+
```

Each `col#` represents a dimension of a 500 dim vector.

---

### Problem:

Given a particular `WORD` value (they are unique), I want to find the 100 `WORD`s which are most similar to it based on the dot product (so an identical `WORD` vector will have a dot product of 1). So for the `WORD` 'CAR' I might get:

```
+--------+------+
|  WORD  |  DOT |
+--------+------+
| CAR    |  1   |
| TRUCK  | 0.89 |
| SEDAN  | 0.86 |
| VEHICLE| 0.81 |
|  ...   |  ... |
| BIKE   | 0.62 |
+--------+------+
```

So (to reiterate) I need to get the dot product of 'CAR' with every other word and sort it descending, and limit it to 100 results.

---

### Potential solutions:

This SO question is very similar and was helpful, but I don't properly understand how to apply it ('garden' is being referred to as a table??).
[Dot product in an SQL table with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745977/dot-product-in-an-sql-table-with-many-columns)

Comment: Can you add data in your question like the other post?

Comment: I'm not sure how he did that, sorry :\

Comment: please read [MY POST](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/2733506) on how to ask a good question. There are tips and tricks for printing out tables like that.. Its just the result of some relevant rows

Comment: Ah, I thought he was using some sort of script. I've made some tables and tried to tidy it up a bit. Cheers

Comment: Thanks that helps :) was my post helpful? Also is there 400k rows all with a different word and 500 cols for that word ??

Comment: Definitely was - it's great to have people like you around that really care about the community. Sorry, so there's 400k rows. Each row has a unique word (stored in the `WORD` column) and a 500 dimensional vector (stored in `COL1`, `COL2`, ..., `COL500`). I updated the table to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Thanks ive used it a bit already lol really useful :) ok so i got that part now you want to multiply every column in Evey row by the other columns to find the greatest? Or a specific column to do the product

Comment: In the example above I need to get the dot product of 'CAR' with every other word and sort it descending, and limit it to 100 results

Comment: OK well I'm on my mobile phone if there isn't an answer when I get home then I'll work up an answer..

Comment: Matt Parker has explained it - thank for your help though! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked SO answer, 'garden' is a table: it's the table `t`, but aliased to `garden`, but limited to a single row (the one for the row with word 'GARDEN').

And for your particular question, you'd need to append 'ORDER BY `DOT` DESC LIMIT 100' to the end of the query.

Perhaps renaming it makes it clearer?

```
select allwords.*,
   (allwords.col0 * word_of_interest.col0 +
    allwords.col1 * word_of_interest.col1 + . . .
    allwords.col500 * word_of_interest.col500
   ) as DOT
from allwords 
cross join
   (select allwords.*
     from allwords
    where `WORD` = '$THE_WORD_I_WANT_EG_CAR'
   ) as `word_of_interest`
order by `DOT` DESC LIMIT 100;
```

As the other answer says, I'd expect this to be fairly slow.  If your COLn vector values are  fairly static I'd consider pre-computing them and storing those results in a separate table that you'd query.

Comment: Ohh I get you - thanks so much! Renaming helped a lot. Regarding pre-computation: The COLn rows are completely static, but `$THE_WORD_THAT_I_WANT_EG_CAR` could be any word in the database, so with that in mind I'd have to store the dot product of every row with each of the other 399,999 rows = ~160,000,000,000 rows, right?

Comment: WAIT - I get you! You mean that I precompute and store the ids of 100 words that are most similar to each row, right? Genius. Thanks so much for your help! :)